# Typing an indirect call to an interface method

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following code that calls a method of an interface using a helper that logs the call:

```
interface Foo {
    A(x: string): Promise<number>
    A(x: string, callback: (value: number) => void): void

    B(x: number): Promise<boolean>
    B(x: number, callback: (value: boolean) => void): void
}


function callFooMethod<Method extends keyof Foo>(foo: Foo, method: Method, arg: any) 
{
    console.log(method)
    return (foo as any)[method](arg)
}
```

How can it be typed without using any?

If I just have:

```
function callFooMethod<Method extends keyof Foo>(foo: Foo, method: Method, arg: any) 
{
    console.log(method)
    return foo[method](arg)
}
```

Typescript complains:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ (x: string): Promise<number>; (x: string, callback: (value: number) => void): void; } | { (x: number): Promise<boolean>; (x: number, callback: (value: boolean) => void): void; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other. ts(2349)
```

I suppose the problem is that in `Method extends keyof Foo` TypeScript assumes that Method has a union type of all method names in Foo, rather than treating it as one of the method names. How can this be addressed?

Comment: Is there a reason the example uses overloaded methods instead of just regular methods? I think the question could probably be answered either way, but in the interest of making code a [mre] it would be nice if there weren’t extra moving parts to the question.

Comment: See previous comment.  If you need to keep those overloads then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Rdw) is how I'd do it.  If not then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb1n2N) is how.  Which of those do we want to pursue here?